# What is the most Interesting and innovative IDE?

Tags: ide, development-environment

As every programmer knows tools are important and there is no tool more important for a developer than the IDE you use to code. In the last few years the IDE-s fall into standards and it is not common to see innovation in this area. What IDE-s you can recommend as innovative and what new ideas and paradigms they introduced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used this but saw the demo video yesterday. The IDE is called [code bubbles](http://www.cs.brown.edu/people/acb/codebubbles_site.htm) and has a unique way of showing and grouping related code together.

That said I find the intellitrace feature in Visual Studio 2010 quite innovative.

Comment: I agree about IntelliTrace. It will change debugging and tracing as we know it.

Comment: Code bubbles looks really interesting. Reminds me of the Smalltalk workspace. I can imagine programming using such an IDE on devices such as the iPad is going to be a kickass experience.

Answer (score 6):

This is by far the coolest set of coding tools yet!

http://vimeo.com/36579366

Answer (score 2):

Palm's Project Ares: http://ares.palm.com/Ares/about.html

It's the IDE for the Palm webOS phones, that runs entirely as a web app. You build and run your app inside the browser, and when you're done, you deploy straight to the cloud.

Answer (score 2):

I'd put my bet on [Meta Programming System](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/) by Jetbrains. The concept is not new but it's the first time it has been implemented on such a huge scale with great IDE support. You create a DSL first, then write programs in that DSL and finally generate code in a target language.

Comment: Read the tuto very hard to grasp, not the DSL concept which is simple, but all the steps required is daunting.

Comment: @user284523 i agree, the example can put off anybody. but look at the bright side - by the time your grandchildren are ready to learn programming, you'd up up to speed and can easily explain it to them.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go for [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/), though I wouldn't want to write a banking system using it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some cool videos of [structured editor prototype](http://blogs.msdn.com/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/09/08/first-videos-of-the-structured-editor-prototype.aspx) that will let you directly code the [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

This is a prototype only and I have no idea if it is still being developed.

Answer (score 0):

One interesting IDE I have seen only on video is [Code Bubbles](http://www.cs.brown.edu/people/acb/codebubbles_site.htm). It opens code snippets as a graph of visual "bubbles". It is really interesting and definitely something I want to try.

Comment: Personally not sure i would call it innovative in a postive way. I see a LOT of problems working on non-trivial code with it. This is more a concept / research idea than a real IDE at that point in time. May well decide to be a dead end practically.

Comment: I saw part of the video on Code Bubbles.  Code Bubbles put me off because, based on my toying with KDE 4 and Eclipse, they most likely render very slowly unless you have new hardware and a decent video driver.  I found KDE 4's folder views (similar in concept to bubbles) disappointing mainly because quirky behavior and missing features got in the way.  However, the developers probably put a lot of work into making Code Bubbles easy to use.